# anonymous hash to array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

For a program I am getting input as

```
{'4#11','6#0','5#2','6#1','7#1','5#11','5#11','5#10','5#8'}
```

from the command line.

This input should be passed into a subroutine as an array without changing the order of elements

```
sub get_height { 
    my (@input1)= @_; 
}
```

How to convert the input into an array without changing the order of elements in perl? If my program is named as four.pl and I am executing the program as

```
perl four.pl {'4#11','6#0','5#2','6#1','7#1','5#11','5#11','5#10'}
```

then in the command line arguments are stored in `$ARGV[0]`. My question is will it be stored as an anonymous hash?

Then I am calling a subroutine `get_height` as below:

```
my $num = get_height($ARGV[0]);
```

Inside the subroutine, how can I change this list into an array so that the order of elements in a list is not changed?

Below is the complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub get_height { 
my (@input1)= @_; 
print "==>@input1\n";
my @array = undef;
my @num = undef;
my $pair = 0;
foreach my $val (@input1)
{
@num = split (/#/,$val);
return -1 if (($num[0] < 4) or ($num[0]>7));
return -1 if (($num[1] < 0) or ($num[1]>11));
$val =~ s/#/./g;
push(@array,$val);
}

for(my $i = 0; $i < $#array; $i++)
{
for(my $j = $i+1; $j < $#array+1; $j++)
    {
    if($array[$i] > $array[$j])
        {
        $pair++;
        }
    }
}
return $pair;
}

my $num = get_height($ARGV[0]);
print "Total pair is $num\n";
```

If I am executing the code as 
perl four.pl {4#11,6#0,5#2,6#1,7#1,5#11,5#11,5#10}, I will get the output as -1.

But I should get the output as 18.

Comment: Some more context is required here. In what format are you receiving the data? Do you need to store it as a hash? How are you calling the subroutine? Describe exactly what you are trying to do and show some more code please.

Comment: If my program is named as four.pl and I am executing the program as perl four.pl {'4#11','6#0','5#2','6#1','7#1','5#11','5#11','5#10'}

Comment: The input is already in an array: `@ARGV`. Did you mean that you want to split the string into substrings, and put the substrings in some array? Why not just remove the curly braces and pass the input as elements, then use `@ARGV`?

Comment: Your input is not a hash, it is a string.

Comment: If it is taken as a string, how to convert it as an array?

Comment: @TLP actually it is not a string, perl converts that to array, so `4#11` is the 0'th index of ARGV and `6#0` is 1'st and so on

Comment: @AnushaN you are passing only 1 number to your function since `$ARGV[0]` stores `4#11`! you have to iterate over your ARGV array and pass items to your function one by one, or pass the whole `@ARGV` and do your stuff inside your function

Comment: @Rocker Perl certainly does no such thing. Perhaps you are thinking of a bash-like shell doing the expansion. You can emulate that with `@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV`. If you were to use this program with another input source than command line, or even in a different shell, it would not work at all.

Comment: Just so you know, I've added a version of your script to my answer with a few changes. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Actually I wonder what this is all about: A string is *not* an array, and the order of elements in an array *does not change* by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the input format you have specified, `@ARGV` looks like this:

```
print "@ARGV\n";
4#11 6#0 5#2 6#1 7#1 5#11 5#11 5#10 5#8
```

i.e. `$ARGV[0] = '4#11'`, `$ARGV[1] = '6#0'`, etc.

This is an array, not a hash.

Note that this is only because the shell you are using has expanded your input before passing it to perl:

```
$ echo {'4#11','6#0','5#2','6#1','7#1','5#11','5#11','5#10','5#8'}
4#11 6#0 5#2 6#1 7#1 5#11 5#11 5#10 5#8
```

It would be much more portable to pass in the input as a list of values separated by spaces, rather than to rely on the shell expansion:

```
perl four.pl '4#11' '6#0' '5#2' '6#1' '7#1' '5#11' '5#11' '5#10' '5#8'
```

You can pass a reference to the whole array like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub get_height { 
    my @input1 = @{$_[0]};   # dereference first argument as array
    print $input1[0];        # output: 4#11
    print $input1[1];        # output: 6#0
}

get_height (\@ARGV);
```

---

Here's a working copy of your script which returns the result that you're expecting. I've made a few changes, which hopefully are fairly self-explanatory. If you're not sure about any of it, let me know:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub get_height { 
    my @heights = @{$_[0]}; 
    print "==>@heights\n";
    my $pair = 0;

    foreach my $val (@heights) {
        my ($feet, $inches) = split /#/, $val;
        return -1 if $feet < 4 or $feet > 7;
        return -1 if $inches < 0 or $inches > 11;
    }

    s/#/./ for @heights;

    for my $i (0..$#heights-1) {
        for my $j ($i+1..$#heights) {
            ++$pair if $heights[$i] > $heights[$j]
        }
    }

    return $pair;
}

my $num = get_height(\@ARGV);
print "Total pair is $num\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

argument line is your @ARGV, so first argument is $ARGV[0]

```
sub get_height { 
my $input1 = $_[0]; 
}

&get_height($ARGV[0])
```

edit: if you can't change the way, the function was called then you can do this

```
sub get_height{
        my (@input1) = @_;

}
get_height(@ARGV);
```

otherwise if you want to pass your numbers one by one then you can do this

```
for(my $i=0; $i<=$#ARGV; $i++){
        get_height($ARGV[$i])
}
```

Comment: I can't change the way, the function is called. I can only change the input after i get it in get_height subroutine

Comment: `{'4#11','6#0','5#2','6#1','7#1','5#11','5#11','5#10','5#8'}` puts your numbers into @ARGV, so passing ARGV array to the function will pass whole your arguments to `@input1`